# Is a simple range sensor described below sufficient to implement particle filter localization?

Tags: localization, particle-filter

I am trying to implement a monte carlo localization/particle filter localization with a simple range sensor. The range sensor only sees in the direction the robot is heading and returns back any obstacle in its line of sight. If there is no obstacle, then the sensor returns back the distance to the boundary wall i.e. there is no maximum range for sensor.

But, the problem is that i am not able to locate the robot's position. Now, I am feeling is it cause the sensor is not powerful enough. Is it feasible to do localization with such a sensor or should I change the sensor type?

Please tell me what you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, this is a single-point range sensor, correct? It is possible to do Monte Carlo localization with such a sensor, but it will take a *very* long time to converge if it does so at all, and will be easily confused. Each additional point you can add when you're doing localization will improve performance, so if you can get a few more of these sensors, you'll do better.